# How to decode an IR from device

Tags: infrared, remote-control, receiver, remote

I have the Mitsubishi DA-R45P receiver, but I don not have a remote for this device. And without remote this device can not work.
I see that there are universal remotes with learn function, but for that you need to have original remote... which i dont have :(

Is it possible to learn codes from device or somehow similar?
I have schematics or receiver, can this help? What are my options?

Comment: Sorry, but no, it is not possible to obtain codes from the receiver.  Additionally questions about the *usage of consumer products* are off-topic here.   You will need to seek assistance from the manufacturer or someone else who has or has recorded the original remote.

Answer (score 1):

As @ChrisStratton syas:  questions about usage of consumer products are off-topic here.

However I feel for you having had the same problem.

I have used universal remotes in the past. They often come with a huge list of TV's which can be selected using a preset code. Even if your TV is not on the list, I had one (can't remember the brand), where you could work your way through each and every one of the preset codes. You might take a weekend off because there were about 900+ codes in it.

It might be simpler and cheaper to order a new remote.

Answer (score 0):

You must somehow figure out the protocol how data is sent, and what the button data is. Sometimes IR remotes have a standard chip inside them so finding the remote controller schematics would help most, or at least finding an identical remote to analyze the protocol and data sent by the buttons. Usually the schematics of the device does not help figuring out the protocol or button codes. (In this case, it is a standard chip, all you need is chip datasheet and use 33.3 kHz for the carrier as it uses a 400 kHz resonator - That is how much I understood from a single chinese datasheet page of Mitsubishi M50142P).

Comment: great. thank you for the all help :) I am going to try find more information for that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i can help, as i had this device in past. but i dont understand schematics.

here are some screenshots from schematics:

device sensor:

[image]

remote:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this won't help at all - from the scematic it is not possible to extract the remote codes.

Comment: You could figure out the points where to attach your logic analyser to, you could get a logic analyser for 10 bucks which does exactly this job.

Comment: can you tell me more how this works ? thanks

Comment: @LukeHappyValley: That does no good at all if you don't have the remote to actually transmit the codes!

Comment: @jusaca In this case it just might be possible to decode protocol and codes because it uses a Mitsubishi M50142P IR transmitter chip used in many other remotes. There is also a Mitsubishi IR protocol so it is possible this uses it. The However, I was not able to find a datasheet for it, maybe someone else can. How these things usually work is that the diodes set the device code and button code comes from how they are connected in the matrix.

Comment: that would be great